# Approximate Mills' Constant

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

## The Task

Write a program or function which, when passed some positive integer `n` as input, returns Mills' Constant accurate up to `n` digits.

## The Definition

Mills' Constant worked out to six thousand digits may be located [here](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/MillsConstant.html).

## Examples

Let `f` be the function described by the challenge.

```
>>> f(1)
1

>>> f(3)
1.31

>>> f(100)
1.306377883863080690468614492602605712916784585156713644368053759966434053766826598821501403701197396
```

## Rules

- Your program must print or return Mills' Constant for any `n` between 1 and 1000.
- Your program must approximate Mills' Constant such that all digits between the first to the `n`th returned or output are accurate to Mills' Constant. Extraneous digits are disallowed.
- No form of hard-coding may be used. This means directly storing the digits of Mills' Constant or storing any of [Mills' Primes](https://oeis.org/A051254) (including those unlisted within OEIS). This rule includes compression. The solution must generate the number, not just output it.
- The final digit must be rounded according to the digit following the final digit. In other words, if digit `n+1` is five or greater, add one to the final digit.
- Built-in functions or constants relating directly to Mills' Constant or the Riemann zeta function may not be used.
- You may assume that the Riemann hypothesis is true.

Comment: Why is `f(1)` 1? 1 is not a prime number. And `floor(1^(3^x))` is 1 for any input.

Comment: @orlp Please read more carefully: the point of the challenge is to approximate the Mills' constant to some digit `n`, where `n` is the input.

Comment: Alright. I was thinking that `f(n)` meant it had to be accurate for the first `n` primes.

Comment: @orlp That would be difficult. There's only been 10 Mills' primes discovered so far, which requires an incredible precision for the Mills' constant.

Comment: May we hardcode the limit of n = 1000?

Comment: @orlp As in, hard coding the number to never go past 1000?

Comment: As in, assuming the input will never go over 1000, and not acquire more precision needed to cover that.

Comment: @orlp Yes, of course.

Comment: The "Definition" section doesn't actually define the number, it just states a property of it. According to Wikipedia, it's defined as the "smallest positive real number" which has that property. Also, some guidance/links for how to calculate it, would be appreciated. Not everyone here is a mathematician...

Comment: @smls This challenge is intentionally difficult. I hope my hints relating to the Riemann zeta function and the Riemann hypothesis are aides enough. I have removed the unnecessary part of the definition section.

Comment: J, 31 bytes: `(":(3^9)%:([:4&p:^&3)^:9]2){.~]` doesn't work because J seems to crash every time it wants to calculate the 7th or greater mills prime. RIP.

Comment: -1 the challenge isn't self contained, and the "definition" link is not particularly helpful

Comment: Difficult != obtuse

Comment: @VoteToClose I think the definition needs to be contained in the question. I shouldn't have to visit an external link to understand the challenge. Thanks. Voting to close as unclear until it's fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2 + gmpy2, <strike>132</strike> 123 bytes

```
from gmpy2 import*
get_context().precision=9999
n=2
exec"n=next_prime(n**3);"*8
print"{:.{}f}".format(root(n,3**9),input())
```

The 9th Mill's prime provides enough precision for 1000 digits. So we calculate that prime, and then use it to calculate the constant.

To speed up the program a lot, replace the exec statement with:

```
mills = [2]
for o in [3, 30, 6, 80, 12, 450, 894, 3636, 70756, 97220, 66768, 300840]:
    mills.append(mills[-1]**3 + o)
n = mills[8]
```

Comment: Ah - going for the Mills' primes method instead of the Riemann zeta. Never considered that. +1

Comment: The loop can be written as `exec"n=next_prime(n**3);"*8`. You can also write `n` as an expression `eval('next_prime('*8+'2'+'**3)'*8)`, but I think that's longer.